# React JS first table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i'm newbie in react js and i want to create a simple table for now without db connection. I create  something like this but i don't know how to create column names. Smb know how to create?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data:
                [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Foo",
                        "age": "20"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "asdas",
                        "age": "30"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "fgdf",
                        "age": "40"
                    }
                ]
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.state.data.map((person, i) => <TableRow key={i}
                                                                  data={person}/>)}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var myStyle = {
            fontSize: 20,
            color: '#2aa445'
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 style={myStyle}>Person Table</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class TableRow extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.data.id}</td>
                <td>{this.props.data.name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.data.age}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

This code show only clera text not table columns and rows:/ This can be only something simple.

Comment: You crate headers the same way: you figure out the names and either code them manually or put them in a collection and iterate, creating a row for the headers, and a `<th>` for each header.

Comment: you should also add table header, for Ex: "<th></th>" ,

Answer (score 2):

Table's in vanilla ReactJS are the same as the ones in HTML. [See here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

The column names are created using the `th` tag. You will also need a row for that (`tr`). In your case the code will look something like this:

```
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
          </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>{this.props.data.id}</td>
                <td>{this.props.data.name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.data.age}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

So for that, you need to add your own styles in order to display the borders and anything else.

For your case in particular, I would say in the `table` and in the `td` tags,you need to add a border style:

```
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This however will make all the content a bit tight in within the border, so give them some padding as well:

```
td {
  padding: 10px
}
```

Edit: here is a nicer version of your table:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
          </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>this.props.data.id</td>
                <td>this.props.data.name</td>
                <td>this.props.data.age</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by this, this is the simplest way to create table dynamically. If you want to add more columns then add same amount of td also. 
and if you want to add style to your table please take a look
[Bootstrap Table](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp)

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>
     COLUMN NAME
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
 {
   data.map((item,index)=>{
     return(<td key={index} > {item} </td>) 
   })
 } 
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need table column header tag

```
<th>Col name 1</th>
```

Here is an example

[image: Edit zkoym3rok4]

Comment: Here you mean? {this.state.data.map((person, i) => RETURN (<TableRow key={i} data={person} />))}. It is not necessary for arrow functions. But glad, you have viewed my example

Comment: You mean here this.props.data.id? No, you may not to define constructor, and this.props would be available automatically

Comment: you are not using any framework that's why you can not see any border aur cell border within your data, you can use css to add customize border just like @theJuls answer, or you can use bootstrap framwork that will give you default table look.

Comment: The question was not about table look, but about table header

Comment: Then check my answer to add table header we use <thead> and to add column in table header add <th>

Comment: Not a problem. Done